# Difficulty with transform from SOAP response

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

From a SOAP response, I received the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindRelativesResponse xmlns="http://avid.com/interplay/ws/assets/types">
  <Results>
    <AssetDescription>
      <InterplayURI>interplay://avideng103?mobid=060a2b340101010101010f0013-000000-53f2ae93b07200c3-060e2b347f7f-2a80</InterplayURI>
      <Attributes>
        <Attribute Name="MOB ID" Group="SYSTEM">060a2b340101010101010f0013-000000-53f2ae93b07200c3-060e2b347f7f-2a80</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="Moniker" Group="SYSTEM">1|F9E3A1A4-4CB9-45CC-A590-77A5D733B633|*|1121558|*</Attribute>
      </Attributes>
    </AssetDescription>
    <AssetDescription>
      <InterplayURI>interplay://avideng103?mobid=060a2b340101010101010f0013-000000-568ad56218ad42e7-060e2b347f7f-2a80</InterplayURI>
      <Attributes>
        <Attribute Name="MOB ID" Group="SYSTEM">060a2b340101010101010f0013-000000-568ad56218ad42e7-060e2b347f7f-2a80</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="Moniker" Group="SYSTEM">1|F9E3A1A4-4CB9-45CC-A590-77A5D733B633|*|4229098|*</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="CATDV RemoteID" Group="USER">11868</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="CATDV Animal" Group="USER">Tortoise</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="CATDV Director Approved" Group="USER">Director Approved</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="CATDV Location" Group="USER">Land</Attribute>
        <Attribute Name="CATDV Time of Day" Group="USER">Day</Attribute>
      </Attributes>
    </AssetDescription>
  </Results>
</FindRelativesResponse>
```

However, my normal attempts at a transform on this are not working.  I've tried the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
<xsl:template match = "/">  

    <test>
        <xsl:value-of select="FindRelativesResponse/Results/AssetDescription/Attributes/Attribute[@Name = 'CATDV RemoteID']"/>
    </test>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, the result would be just empty in the test element.

I'm wondering if it has something to do with this: `<FindRelativesResponse xmlns="http://avid.com/interplay/ws/assets/types">` I'm not used to seeing that so I'm wondering if there's a step I'm missing in the xslt.

Here is additional information needed to help answer the question.  I have multiple namespaces and am not sure how to get them to work properly as listed above.  Here's what I've tried so far, specifically on the 4th `<soa:Parameter>` listed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:avid="http://avid.com/interplay/ws/assets/types"
    xmlns:soa="urn:telestream.net:soa:core"
    exclude-result-prefixes="avid"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:template match = "/">  

    <soa:Label>
    <soa:Parameter type="string" identifier="7c0c6642-5a4d-42b7-9945-303caffd2c57" bindable="True" name="CATDV Time of Day" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
        <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
    </soa:Parameter>
    <soa:Parameter type="string" identifier="ced9fe1e-d546-4b2e-9dd8-4ad94d701802" bindable="True" name="CATDV Director Approved" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
        <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
    </soa:Parameter>
    <soa:Parameter type="string" identifier="16aba128-da36-4e3e-b68a-b95792b15be8" bindable="True" name="CATDV Location" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
        <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
    </soa:Parameter>
    <soa:Parameter type="string" identifier="930630e1-7697-4514-9aa4-d00d536db664" bindable="True" name="CATDV Animal" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
        <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
    </soa:Parameter>
        <soa:Parameter type="string" identifier="6a2319d4-4894-4268-8f71-186c2b8cf39a" bindable="True" name="CATDV Remote ID" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1"><xsl:value-of select= "avid:FindRelativesResponse/avid:Results/avid:AssetDescription/avid:Attributes/avid:Attribute[@Name = 'CATDV Remote ID']"></xsl:value-of>
        <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
    </soa:Parameter>
    <soa:Parameter type="string" identifier="7a05829d-0a73-4cf0-a075-ef4d26f95c2a" bindable="True" name="Reference Asset MOB ID" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
        <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
    </soa:Parameter>
    </soa:Label>

</xsl:template>     

  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it has something to do with this:
>   `<FindRelativesResponse
>   xmlns="http://avid.com/interplay/ws/assets/types">`

It most certainly does. Try it this way:

***-- edited to fit your newly added requrement: --***

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soa="urn:telestream.net:soa:core"
xmlns:avid="http://avid.com/interplay/ws/assets/types"
exclude-result-prefixes="avid">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/> 

<xsl:template match="/">  
    <soa:Label>
        <soa:Parameter type="string" identifier="7c0c6642-5a4d-42b7-9945-303caffd2c57" bindable="True" name="CATDV Time of Day" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
            <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
        </soa:Parameter>
        <soa:Parameter type="string" identifier="ced9fe1e-d546-4b2e-9dd8-4ad94d701802" bindable="True" name="CATDV Director Approved" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
            <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
        </soa:Parameter>
        <soa:Parameter type="string" identifier="16aba128-da36-4e3e-b68a-b95792b15be8" bindable="True" name="CATDV Location" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
            <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
        </soa:Parameter>
        <soa:Parameter type="string" identifier="930630e1-7697-4514-9aa4-d00d536db664" bindable="True" name="CATDV Animal" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
            <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
        </soa:Parameter>
        <soa:Parameter type="string" identifier="6a2319d4-4894-4268-8f71-186c2b8cf39a" bindable="True" name="CATDV Remote ID" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
            <xsl:value-of select="avid:FindRelativesResponse/avid:Results/avid:AssetDescription/avid:Attributes/avid:Attribute[@Name = 'CATDV RemoteID']"/>
            <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
        </soa:Parameter>
        <soa:Parameter type="string" identifier="7a05829d-0a73-4cf0-a075-ef4d26f95c2a" bindable="True" name="Reference Asset MOB ID" enabled="true" disableable="false" optionseditable="false" row="-1" column="-1" columnspan="1">
            <soa:IsRequired>false</soa:IsRequired>
        </soa:Parameter>
    </soa:Label>
</xsl:template>     

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I see, it's namespaces.  How would that work then if you have multiple namespaces, such as: <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:avid="http://avid.com/interplay/ws/assets/types"
    xmlns:soa="urn:telestream.net:soa:core"
    exclude-result-prefixes="avid"
    version="1.0">

Comment: @RyanJensen I don't see why you need the `xmlns:xs` and `xmlns:soa` namespace declarations. They are not used anywhere.

Comment: They are, but until I understood the namespaces I unfortunately left at that part in an attempt at clarity.  I added the changes to the original question to clarify.

Comment: @RyanJensen See if my edited answer works for you. Note that your XML contains `Name="CATDV RemoteID"`, not `Name="CATDV Remote ID"` as shown in your attempt.